# Why do we discuss "well-formed XML" like it's something special?

Tags: xml

I understand why we distinguish "well-formed XML" from "valid XML." But why do we distinguish "well-formed XML" as something special? Is there such a thing as "not well-formed XML"? Wouldn't that just be "not XML?"

For instance, no one introduces regular expressions by listing the features of "well-formed regex." They just say "regex has xyz syntax; anything else is wrong."

Is this just a convention of discourse, or is there more to the story?

Comment: According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document), "valid" means the XML conforms to a DTD, while "well formed" just means it can be parsed as XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I agree with you that ill-formed XML is "not XML." However, when actually writing tools such as parsers, it's useful to distinguish something that is trying to be XML but has a few errors from something that is completely wrong or is not intended to be XML. If you prefer to say "has syntactic or semantic errors" rather than "not well formed", that's fine; it's just more verbose than necessary.

Part of this is also because XML was originally sketched as a subset/substiset of SGML (the markup system that HTML was built on top of). The well-formed XML document is a subset of the well-formed SGML document, and that's another useful distinction for folks designing the software which processes these or languages which build on top of them. (It's possible for an HTML document to be interpretable as well-formed XML, but most HTML documents aren't. Heck, most HTML documents aren't even really correct HTML... but that's a different rant.)

Finally, this is a matter of the direction you're approaching it from. When you're writing standards, that's closer to language design than to the usual kinds of "whittle it into shape" programming. You're working with grammars, not with code. And at the grammar level, "well formed" is a significant technical statement. I would bet that the folks who formalized regular expressions *did* use this term, even if the folks who first invented them didn't. So this can be considered a "term of art" -- a phrase that has a specific meaning and set of connotations to folks working in a particular area -- which you're more aware of than in most cases because XML is newer and its inventors attempted to standardize it from the beginning rather than letting it develop and standardizing it later. (Which brings up another rant about the order in which the standards had to be developed rather than the order in which they should have been developed, but that too is for another day.)

Answer (score 3):

I agree, the adjective "well-formed" is redundant. If it's not well-formed, it's not XML.

The existence of the adjectives allows one to form sentences like "The parser says my XML is not well-formed". I think it would be better in theory to use the sentence "The parser says my input is not XML"; however, that's wishful thinking.

The origin of the adjective is as a contrast to "valid". "The input doesn't have to be valid, but it must be well-formed." They could have said "The input doesn't have to be valid, but it must conform to the XML grammar". But if someone said simply "The input doesn't have to be valid, but it must be XML" then people might not get the message.

In normal life we do this kind of thing all the time. We talk about "correct English", or we say "I want Java code that compiles cleanly". If it's incorrect, is it English? If it doesn't compile cleanly, is it Java code? Redundancy in everyday language isn't necessarily a bad thing, but in this case I think it has confused as many people as it enlightens.

Comment: Good point about English. And the point about distinguishing it from "valid XML" of course begs the question: why did they call it "valid XML" instead of something more jargon-y sounding (and therefore less confusing) like "validated XML?" This is this same problem we have in statistics with words like "normal," "regular" and "standard."